# Elegant with sharp thing, Who am I?

Tags: riddle

I am more elegant than others.

I am looks like one of animal but I am still mystery and not exist.

I have things which my duplicate haven't.

Impressive for children, Found in their thought and dreams.

They also like to play with me.

Royal Arm for heraldic with heavy wings.

Who am I?

Comment: Not sure if the small grammatical errors were intended in line 2 but the first letters of each word forms "IASLOBIASMANE" which might be "I A SLOB, I A SMANE". Probably a coincidence?

Comment: if the strange grammar ("elegant than" is odd, I would expect "more elegant than", "same like one" is also odd, etc) is deliberate, please say so. If not, please fix it or ask others to do so.

Comment: Edited two lines...  Sorry for poor English..  actually English is not maah mother tongue..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like a

> Unicorn

I am more elegant than others.

> It really looks elegant.

I am looks like one of animal but I am still mystery and not exist.

> It looks like horse but still it do not exist.

I have things which my duplicate haven't.

> It have a horn but we cannot find it in horse.

Impressive for children, Found in their thought and dreams.

They also like to play with me.

> Children love it (even i love them). They play with their toys.

Royal Arm for heraldic with heavy wings.

> It is shown as a wing for Scotland in the Royal Arm for heraldic.
>  Example..as below image
>  [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgib4.png)

Elegant with sharp thing

> Its sharp thing is it's horn.

Comment: Yes, But you have to elaborate all the clue with your solutions..after that i will accept your answer.. :)